# Vertically center an element in another element in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

Please check out this CSS:

```
body {
    margin: 50px 0px; padding: 0px;
}

.one {
background: #151515;
height: 700px;
width: 900px;
margin: 0px auto;
padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}

#two {
background: #e6e6e6;
height: 140px;
width: 900px;
}
```

(http://jsfiddle.net/UvvPC/)

I want to use margin-top to move the grey box in the CSS above.

I want the grey box to be in the middle of the black box but I have been told margin-top does not go well with internet explorer.

What do I use instead?

Comment: Why would IE have problems with margin-top?

Answer (score 1):

Use margin-bottom on the element before it :)

Answer (score 1):

Using `display: table-cell` won't work in IE6-7. If that's a concern for you, you could use the following technique :

```
.one {
  background: #151515;
  height: 700px;
  width: 900px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  position: relative;
}

.two {
  background: #e6e6e6;
  height: 140px;
  width: 900px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -70px; /* half of the height */
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HYjke/

Comment: take a look at: http://jsfiddle.net/nHdAp/ i want it to look like that in internet explorer but in internet explorer the text isn't in the centre of the input its at the top and the shadow doesn't show up. How can this be changed?

Comment: As your initial question has been answered, you should mark a post as an answer and open up another question for this other problem. It's going to be easier that way for other people facing the same bug finding an answer later on. I could probably take a look at it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8280703/why-does-the-input-text-have-a-different-position-and-input-shadow-not-show-in-i

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why do you need to use `margin-top` to do this task. This may help you:

```
.one {
    background: #151515;
    height: 700px;
    width: 900px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Comment: Ah thanks. I see you can make a circle shape using CSS 3 BUT internet explorer doesn't support this. how can i make a circle shape in css that internet explorer will support?

Comment: which version of Internet explorer do you use?

Comment: i believe its the latest one, but is there no way to make a css circle compatible across all internet explorer browsers?