# Why does the input text have a different position and input shadow not show in internet explorer?

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

Take a look at:

http://jsfiddle.net/nHdAp

want it to look like that in internet explorer but in internet explorer the text isn't in the centre of the input its at the top and the shadow doesn't show up. How can this be changed?

There must be a way!

Comment: There's a [css-cross-browser] tag?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `line-height: 29px` on your input will probably fix your text alignement problem. As for the box-shadow property, only IE9 and up supports it. See this link for reference : http://caniuse.com/#search=box-shadow

Comment: Ah thanks, is there a way of making the shadow i have compatible for IE9?

Comment: You could always use filters, but you'll probably never get something perfectly accurate. I'd personnaly suggest you just forget about the shadows in IE8 and lowers, as it's probably not crucial to your users anyway. If you still want to try IE filters, you can take a look at this blog post : http://ole-laursen.blogspot.com/2009/08/using-css3-box-shadow-with-ie.html

Comment: Ah ok thanks for the help, just wondered how can i make an input autofocus in IE?

Comment: Also say I wanted a div to appear on the IE browser but not on the Safari/chrome ect. how is that done?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8280988/how-to-make-input-autofocus-in-internet-explorer