# How to make input autofocus in internet explorer?

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

Please check out my JSFiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/WK2N3/1/

```css
#searchbar {
float: left;
display: inline;
background: #FFFFFF;
height: 29px;
width: 660px;
border: 1px solid #bdbdbd;
margin: 55px 0px 0px 10px;
font-size : 17px;
font-family : Georgia;
font : 17px Georgia, Times, âTimes New Romanâ, serif;
color : #333333;
}

#searchbar:focus {
float: left;
display: inline;
background: #FFFFFF;
height: 29px;
width: 660px;
border: 1px solid #2e9afe;
margin: 55px 0px 0px 10px;
font-size : 17px;
font-family : Georgia;
font : 17px Georgia, Times, âTimes New Romanâ, serif;
color : #333333;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 2px #2e9afe;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 2px#2e9afe;
box-shadow: 0 0 2px #2e9afe;
}

input:focus {
outline : none;
}
```

```html
<form><input type="text" id="searchbar" autofocus="autofocus"/></form>
```

How can I make this on autofocus like it is for chrome, safari, opera and firefox for IE?

Answer (score 34):

Here's a one-liner (well, one line of actual logic) that uses jQuery to make autofocus work in IE. It bails out if the focus is already set--in other words, in any HTML5-capable browser.

```
$(function() {
  $('[autofocus]:not(:focus)').eq(0).focus();
});
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/WK2N3/88/) is an updated jsFiddle that works in IE.

Comment: What if there is (by mistake) *two* elements with the `autofocus` attribute? In compliant browsers, won't this code then find the second (unfocused) element and set the focus there instead?

Comment: No, @xec, that's what the `.eq(0)` is for. Besides, if there are two `autofocus` elements then that's a bug in the page and it really doesn't matter which one gets the focus, right?

Comment: The `.eq(0)` is called after the `:not(:focus)` selector is ran, so that doesn't make a difference. I agree that it's not a big issue though, it is only a bug when the html is invalid. In any case, i believe `$('[autofocus]').focus()` should be sufficient.

Comment: jsFiddle doesn't support IE. That's... inconvenient.

Comment: Sorry about that. jsFiddle supported IE when I wrote the original answer.

Comment: And vanilla JS: `autofocusWannaBe = document.querySelector([autofocus]:not(:focus)"); if (autofocusWannaBe) autofocusWannaBe.focus();`

Answer (score 3):

You will have to rely on javascript to do this, since html5 autofocus is not supported in IE. There is a good blog post about it here : https://www.html5tutorial.info/html5-autofocus.php

Basically, you first check if the attribute is supported, and then use javascript to manually focus in said input using the `focus()` method if it is not.

Comment: As of today, 12/13/2016, the autofocus keyword works in IE 11.0.36 on Windows 10 but not on IE 11.0.35 on Windows 7.How very irritating.

Answer (score 2):

Usually I use jQuery:

```
$('input').focus()
```

Live example: https://jsfiddle.net/simply_simpy/eb4JJ/5/

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
setTimeout(function() { document.getElementById('myInput').focus(); }, 10);
```

for more detail [AutoFOcusIE](https://www.mkyong.com/javascript/focus-is-not-working-in-ie-solution/)

Answer (score -3):

autofocus in IE is is just

```
<input type="text" id="searchbar" autofocus />
```

not

```
<input type="text" id="searchbar" autofocus="autofocus"/>
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh441087(v=vs.85).aspx for more info.

Comment: You're wrong. Both syntaxes work in all browsers that support `autofocus`. However, Internet Explorer supports it only from version 10.