# Autofocus HTML5 attribute not working for IE9

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'. developing for IE9 and the HTML5 autofocus keyword which puts the cursor in the specified input field doesn't work. How can I add that functionality in IE9 (IE11 but forced down to IE9)?

---

The following won't work:

- `$('input').focus()`
- `$(function() {$('[autofocus]:not(:focus)').eq(0).focus();});`
- `setTimeout(function() { document.getElementById('myInput').focus(); }, 10);`

---

As suggested:

HTML

```
<body>
<form>
    <h3>Find Item</h3>
    <input maxlength="8" name="abcd" id="abcd" autofocus="autofocus" placeholder="Find Item" required>
</form>
```

JS

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#wordOrderID").focus();
   }
</script>
```

Comment: $("#wordOrderID").remove(); ??, you are deleting the input here

Comment: may be you need to wait till document is loaded, are you using this?
$(document).ready(function(){  $("#wordOrderID").remove();   });

Comment: No reason either of those approaches shown shouldn't work, assuming element exists when they are called and some other element isn't being focused after. Provide [mcve]

Comment: Take a look at the accepted answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600186/focus-doesnt-work-in-ie)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make input autofocus in internet explorer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8280988/how-to-make-input-autofocus-in-internet-explorer)

Comment: This might help you solve you problem. http://stackoverflow.com/a/9935993/6601303

Comment: You can remove the `this.` from your `jQuery` call.

Comment: `this` is `document` and `$` is a window property. Using `this.$` makes no sense

Comment: updated @m_callens (I was experimenting), thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

Checked JS console and was surprised to see an error even tho my code in that page is 10 lines long. Removed problematic code and `$('input').focus();` works!