# Invoke spell check when loading the page

Tags: javascript, html

I'm creating a HTML textarea form on IE 11, when loading the page, the form will be filled with value from database. When user begin to type, the browser will do the spell check, but when user loadS the page, the text in the textarea has no spell check.

Is there a way to force to add red spell check underlines when onload?

Comment: `focus()`ing it might work.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you provide the code?

Comment: You can try reading about spellcheck attr. Its experimental and looks like the default is `true` for IE and text areas. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/spellcheck

Comment: I did try focus() with spellcheck attribute on IE, but it doesn't populate red underlines when onload :(

Answer (score 0):

Add autofocus to the element.

```html
<textarea id="myTextArea" spellcheck="true"  autofocus="autofocus">Ths is the text from the dtabase that's loaded on page load.</textarea>
```

For Internet Explorer, try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8280988/how-to-make-input-autofocus-in-internet-explorer):

```
$(function() {
  $('[autofocus]:not(:focus)').eq(0).focus();
});
```

Comment: focus() does work, but the spellcheck doesn't put red underlines when page loads.